# Bathroom Faucet Removal

Tags: bathroom, faucet, removal, bathroom-fixtures

[image][image][image]I am trying to remove a bathroom faucet that looks separate on top but is all connected underneath (all 3 pieces). I have gotten the hot and cold handles off and the unit would drop out the bottom if it weren't for the center part, which is still connected to the faucet on top. There is a plate directly against the counter underneath and so I can't access or see what is keeping the middle component in place. There is nothing external on the top to release it and while it will wiggle back-and-forth, it makes a squeaking sound like it is screwed into something. There is no nut underneath that I can see so I suspect there is something under the plate. The plate cannot pry off, and I am afraid of breaking my granite. Any ideas?

Comment: A picture would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not plumber but there is likely a screw in the center hole of the faucet that disconnects it from the faucet body underneath.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The center hole was where the drain handle was located--it is a hole straight through to the bottom.

Comment: Are there any screws in the decor ring at the base of the faucet? Perhaps there is a screw underneath there?

Comment: do not understand the function of the plate

Comment: The centre part looks like a nut to me.  There may be a grunb screw at the back of the tap.